# PHP - How to start my count from 5000

Tags: php

How can i start the count from 5000 and count from there in my following code.

here is my code.

```
$i=1;
while($i<=19000){
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I favorited this so I can prove questions like this exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could initialize `$i` to the right value, before beginning looping :

```
$i=5000;
while($i<=19000){
    $i++;
}
```

And/or you could rewrite your code to use a [**`for`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop :

```
for ($i=5000 ; $i<=19000 ; $i++) {
    // use $i
}
```

In this kind of situations, using a `for` loop, instead of while, might make your code easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Is that **real question**? Try:

```
$i = 5000;
while($i <= 19000){
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Learning basics of programming seems needed: Have a look at the [Introduction to Programming](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Programming) ... Go through the exercises there.

If you are interested in learning how to program using PHP have a look at [Introduction to programming using PHP](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/isd/common/resources/programming/programming_intro_php)

Answer (score 0):

simply initialise $i with 5000